# Problem plotting partial sum of a Fourier series

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, trigonometry, piecewise

I'm new to using Mathematica, and I have a problem with plotting Fourier series partial sums.

In particular, my target is

1. to plot the Fourier series of my piecewise function and with that function on a single plot
2. and then to compare the genereted trigonometric polynomial with the original function to find point where they are closest to each other.

I started with this piecewise function which was generated by a previous fitting of my data.

```
f[x_] := 
  Piecewise[
    {{1595.6662770406633 - 4.968000370422044 x + 0.012672971318651484 x^2 - 
        0.00001183377889695339 x^3 + 3.841543896820609*^-9 x^4, 
      0 <= x < 1266.}, 
     {140884.53677307916 - 397.17060928335155 x + 0.44179779820265586 x^2 - 
        0.0002399273183663781 x^3 + 6.376241982891033*^-8 x^4 - 
          6.639720201538734*^-12 x^5, 
      1266. <= x < 2530.}}, 
    0]
```

[image]

By hand, I calculated the Fourier coefficients (I hope they're correct) in this way:

```
a0 = (1/2529) Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2529}]; 
ak1 = 
  Integrate[
    (1/2)(1595.67 - 4.968 x + 0.012673 x^2 - 0.0000118338 x^3 + (3.84154 x^4)/10^9) Cos[k π x/2], 
    {x, 0, 1265}, 
    Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]; 
ak2 = 
  Integrate[
    (1/2)(140885. - 397.171 x + 0.441798 x^2 - 0.000239927 x^3 + (6.37624 x^4)/10^8 - (6.63972 x^5)/10^12) Cos[k π x/2], 
    {x, 1266, 2592}, 
    Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]; 
bk1 = 
  Integrate[
    (1/2) Sin[k π x/2]*(1595.67 - 4.968 x + 0.012673 x^2 - 0.0000118338 x^3 + (3.84154 x^4)/10^9), 
    {x, 0, 1265}, 
    Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]]; 
bk2 = 
  Integrate[
    (1/2)(140885. - 397.171 x + 0.441798 x^2 - 0.000239927 x^3 + (6.37624 x^4)/10^8 - (6.63972 x^5)/10^12) Sin[k π x/2], 
   {x, 1266, 2529}, 
   Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers]; 
ak = FullSimplify[ak1 + ak2, k ∈ Integers]
bk = FullSimplify[bk1 + bk2, k ∈ Integers]
```

And then, to plot my partial sum, I defined:

```
s[n_, x_] := a0/2+(1/2530) Sum[ak Cos[(k π x)/2] + k Sin[(k π x)/2], {k, 1, n}]

partialsums = Table[s[n, x], {n, 1, 5}]

Plot[Evaluate[partialsums], {x, 0, 20}]
```

But the following is the result I see when I try to plot my partial sums and `f` together in a same range, for example, of 20.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[partialsums], f[x_]}, {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

In other words, Mathematica doesn't plot the partial sums together with my original function I want to compare it with.

I also tried with

```
  Plot[{s[1, x], f[x_]}, {x, 0, 2530}]
```

[image]

But that doesn't work either. Moreover the function generated by the partial sums doesn't seem to follow the curvature of `f` and its amplitude.

I think I have probably made some mistakes in the calculus of the coefficients or in definition of variables, and until this is corrected, I can't go on with my analisys.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: The way to combine two plots is:  `Show[Plot[f1, {x,0,20}],Plot[f2,{x,0,20}]` or `Plot[{f1[x],f2[x]},{x,0,20}]`.

Comment: try `Plot[Evaluate@Append[partialsums, f[x]], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: What is `f[x_]` ? what is `price`? Further `a0` should be divided by two, shouldn't be?...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas thanks for note to me. I made mistake in coping it from my .nb file. By the way, now I substituted "price" with the  right value (it was the length of the sample) and correct a0 dividing by two (too much fast in copy the script, sorry), so the question should be more clear.

Comment: I have not so much time, but I can see several errors in your calculations. Your period in the functions `Sin` and `Cos` is not included ($1/2529$). In `s[n_,x_]`definition, `k` should be `bk`. Please, look for more typos and errors, it could there be more...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas When do you have much time, could you explain better the elements I have to correct and in which way ? It would be really helpful for me to solve this task....Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I propose after correcting typos and errors. As the function in limited to an interval (band-limited), Fourier Analysis is valid considering that your function is periodic, with a period being the interval length. Thus, you can do this analysis. Otherwise, you should do Fourier Transform:

```
a0 = (2/2529)*(Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2529}]);
ak[n_?NumericQ] := (2/2529)*(NIntegrate[f[x]*Cos[2 \[Pi] n x/2529], {x, 0, 2529}]);
bk[n_?NumericQ] := (2/2529)*(NIntegrate[f[x]*Sin[2 \[Pi] n x/2529], {x, 0, 2529}]);
s[0, x_] := a0/2;
s[k_ /; k != 0, x_] := s[0, x] + 
Sum[ak[n]*Cos[2 \[Pi] n x/2529] + bk[n]*Sin[2 \[Pi] n x/2529], {n, 
 1, k}];
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], s[n, x]}, {x, offset, offset + range}, 
PlotRange -> {offset, offset + range}, {800, 2800}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False], 
{{n, 0, "Number of Terms"}, 0, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{range, 10, "x-interval"}, 0, 2529 - offset, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{offset, 0, "Offset x-value"}, 0, 2529 - range, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

You can play with the number of terms, origin of analysis (x-axis origin), and range of x-values.

### EDIT

A more compact code (assuming 50 terms for the sum):

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@{f[x], a0/2 + Sum[coeffs[[n]].(#[2 \[Pi] n x/2529] & /@ {Cos, Sin}), 
{n, 1, k}]}, {x, offset, offset + range}, 
PlotRange -> {{offset, offset + range}, {800, 2800}}, Frame -> True,
Axes -> False], 
{{k, 0, "Number of Terms"}, 0, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{range, 10, "x-interval"}, 0, 2529 - offset, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
{{offset, 0, "Offset x-value"}, 0, 2529 - range, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
ContinuousAction -> False, 
Initialization :> (coeffs = Table[(2/2529)*(NIntegrate[f[x]*(#[2 \[Pi] n x/2529] & /@ {Cos, Sin}), 
{x, 0,2529}]), {n, 1, 50}]; 
a0 = (2/2529)*(Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2529}]))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @José. Very helpfull and clear.
By the way,you keep in mind to me another related problem,based on your answer.
In particular,the piecewise f I used in my analisys comes from a fitting of a timeseries,so it's surely not a "periodic function".
And, since you state that "Fourier Analysis is valid considering that your function is periodic,with a period being the interval length.Thus,you can do this analysis.Otherwise,you should do Fourier Transform".
Then,how I could solve the same task with a continuos Fourier Transform?Couldn't be problems with discontinuity point?

Comment: @GiuseppeVonella Fourier transform can be done for functions with finite discontinuity points. Please, acknowledge the help from contributors by accepting/voting their answers. Happy to help :))